# Зачем нужны параметры newp, newLen в функции sysctl()?

Tags: c++, c, freebsd

В [документации по функции `sysctl`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sysctl(3)) написано следующее:

> To set a new value, `newp` is set to  point to a buffer of length `newlen`
>   from which the requested value is to be taken. If a new value is not
>   to be set, `newp` should be set to NULL and `newlen` set to 0.

Но я не могу понять, что это означает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дословный перевод:

> Чтобы установить новое значение, `newp` указывает на буфер длиной
>   `newlen`, из которого берется запрашиваемое значение. Если новое
>   значение не устанавливается, то `newp` должен быть задан в `NULL`, а
>   `newlen` в 0.

Comment: мне не дословный нужен, а смысловой

Comment: @van9petryk а что непонятно в дословном? Функция для установки и чтения данных. Нужно читать - используется `oldp`/`oldlenp`, писать - `newp`/`newlen`.

Comment: Забыл что функция используется также для установки. Поэтому возникали всякие догадки по поводу new, newlen.

Comment: @van9petryk читайте документацию внимательнее: `get or set system information`.